# jmespath - how to search a json path with number as id?

Tags: python, quoting, jmespath

I have a JSON like below and need to search the path 'root['quiz']['maths']['1']'.  How is this possible?

My original JSON below:

```
 {
   "dictionary_item_added":{
      "root['quiz']['maths']['Corozno']":{
         "question":"5 + 7 = ?",
         "options":[
            "10",
            "11",
            "12",
            "13"
         ],
         "answer":"12"
      },
      "root['quiz']['maths']['1']":{
         "question":"12 - 8 = ?",
         "optio8ns":[
            "1",
            "20",
            "3",
            "4"
         ],
         "answer":"4"
      }
   },
   }
}
```

Comment: have you tried `["1"]["question"]`?

Comment: Do you have that as a dictionary in python, or as a json file / string?

Comment: its as a json file

Comment: get this error:
ParseError: Expecting: ['quoted_identifier', 'unquoted_identifier', 'lbracket', 'lbrace'], got: number: Parse error at column 11, token "1" (NUMBER), for expression:
"quiz.maths.1"

Comment: What code gives you that error? As far as JSON is concerned, the key is an opaque string. As far as JMESPath is concerned, it's not clear what document those keys as path expressions refer to.

Comment: My code: 
json_2 = json.load(open(r'D:\DATA\json_2.json','r'))
#print(json_2)

print(jmespath.search("quiz.maths.1", json_2))

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue, missed quotes:

print(jmespath.search('quiz.maths."1"', json_2))

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue, need to enclose numbers quotes: print(jmespath.search('quiz.maths."1"', json_2))